# Is nose an extension of unittest?

Tags: python, testing, nose

I'm about to use nose as a method for test discovery on my already implemented unittest classes in my rather large project. I was under the impression that nose is just used primarily for test discovery and test running (in parallel as well). But I see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5696884/python-nose-vs-unittest) as if nose is a replacement for unittest. Can someone clarify what they meant here? Am I missing some core piece of functionality that nose provides?

As a side note, what is the difference between py.test and nose?

Comment: since Python 2.7, `unittest` also provides discovery, so if that's your goal you can do just with the stdlib

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [docs](http://code.google.com/p/python-nose/) for nose say:

> nose provides an **alternate** test discovery and running process for
>   unittest, one that is intended to mimic the behavior of py.test as
>   much as is reasonably possible without resorting to too much magic.

If you [take a peek at the code](http://code.google.com/p/python-nose/source/browse/nose/case.py), you will see that unittest is one of the dependencies.

```
import logging
import sys
import unittest
```

So - to the best of my knowledge - I would say that nose is a drop-in ***alternative*** for running tests, but not an *replacement* to the unittest module (playing a bit with the semantics here, but I hope this is clear enough).

Answer (score 8):

Nose mimics behavior of py.test. That's what they say on their [website](http://code.google.com/p/python-nose/):

> nose provides an alternate test discovery and running process for unittest, one that is intended to mimic the behavior of py.test as much as is reasonably possible without resorting to too much magic

Nose is an **extension** of unittest and adds the features listed in issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5696884/python-nose-vs-unittest.

Comment: This seems reasonable.  Nose is certainly based on unittest.  It subclasses and replaces the unittest loader and runner, and radically extends their capabilities.